# Swiping to see next or previous pages on mobile devices

Tags: ipad, swipe

My client wants a website specifically for iPads containing 3 pages. Instead of a menu to navigate between these pages, he wants to swipe leftward / rightward anywhere on the screen to see the next page or the previous page. The 3 "pages" of the site would then be `div` elements belonging to the same html page, with only the one corresponding to the current "page" being visible. The markup would look like this:

```
<div id='page1'>
    content page1
</div>
<div id='page2' class='current'>
    content page2
</div>
<div id='page3'>
    content page3
</div>
```

I did find a few little solutions here and there (for example [this one](http://designicu.com/jquery-mobile-swipe/)) but nothing very established/popular. Am I missing something, is there a reliable and easy way to swipe between pages on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something "established", there's Dojo mobile:
http://dojotoolkit.org/features/mobile

I've used it before. The only problem I've found is it's built by default to adapt the look of your site to match the look of the OS of the device it's being displayed on (which is totally under your control whether you want to use their CSS, I just don't like the idea.)

EDIT:
On that note if they want a "website specifically for iPads" why not just build an iPad app? Websites are not meant for any single particular device to be viewing them.

Comment: I went for Owl Carousel, with slides exactly as big as the screen. Perfect solution.